# What font is used in these wooden trail signs?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I originally thought the standard was Helvetica, but looking at these examples we see the font is narrower and the 'R' doesn't look like Helvetica.

Also, these signs are typically routed -- so the router will give a rounded profile to sharp corners.

Does anyone know what font is used here, or anything that comes close?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The US Federal Highway Administration (FHWA) has a [thorough set of guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_on_Uniform_Traffic_Control_Devices) for all of its signage. You can purchase the fonts through [DGI Traffic](http://www.fhwa.org).

**The type used by the Forest Service** is referred to as ASA Series C in the FS docs. The FHWA more commonly refers to the type as *FHWA Series* fonts but they appear to be the same. That name is applied to both the routed and printed type. You can read up on some of the specs at the [Sign and Poster Guidelines for the Forest Service](http://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/stelprd3810021.pdf) (PDF) page. Section 14.4 speaks to the routed signs.

**The FHWA type is available in Series A-F,** A being the narrowest, F being the widest. The document [Standard Alphabets For Traffic Control Devices](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/SHSe/Alphabets.pdf) (PDF) shows the types in all their glory with the spacing parameters.

**Tobias Frere-Jones produced a full-featured replica** under the name [Interstate](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/interstate/).

Answer (score 7):

Generally these are single line/stroke fonts for Computer Numerical Control (CNC) machines. Most don't have a specific name or foundry. They simply are supplied with CNC software from the manufacturer.

CNC machines are computer driven cutters/engravers used in manufacturing many items which need to be custom shaped or carved. I suspect signs such as those are carved by machines. Most likely CNC machines, but there is a possibility that laser engravers were used. In the case of laser engravers, any font will work.

You can find several single stroke fonts if you google for "CNC Fonts"

http://ncplot.com/stickfont/stickfont.htm

http://www.mrrace.com/CamBam_Fonts/

Answer (score 2):

US Forest Service signs do use ASA 2000 fonts, with varying font thicknesses, depending on the type & size of the sign for area clear cutting, but EM-7100 shows TD-x trail signs have a 1/8" width on all lettering strokes.

A freebie version is available of ASA 2000 called "Blue Highway" for large forest signs (it comes with the various width versions), and a simple open vector ASA font for trail signs.

I've gone through every letter, though, to adjust cutting start, sequence, and direction to maximize speed and minimize tear-out, and make other small adjustments in kerning, especially for fractions.  Despite the 1/8" stroke spec. in EM-7100, I now use a 5/32" end mill, which really looks great, but will increase your sign width by 10% or so.